# Email template for contact form in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, contact-form

I have extended contact email form and added few fields(Refer screenshot)

[image]

Under subject field there are 3 options, based on the subject selected the email should be send to multiple users.

For example, if option 1 is selected it should be sent to only aaa@gmail.com,ccc@gamil.com.
If Option 2 is selected it should be sent to only bbb@gmail.com, eee@gmail.com

My controller file

**/var/www/html/ajaffe/app/code/Amy/Contactform/Controller/Index/Post.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Amy\Contactform\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var MailInterface
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param MailInterface $mail
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LoggerInterface $logger = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $contactsConfig);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->isPostRequest()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        try {
            $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us. Your inquiry was submitte and will be responded to you as soon as possible.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('contact_us');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/index');
    }

    /**
     * @param array $post Post data from contact form
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendEmail($post)
    {
        $this->mail->send(
            $post['subject'], 
            $post['email'],
            ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isPostRequest()
    {
        /** @var Request $request */
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        return !empty($request->getPostValue());
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function validatedParams()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (trim($request->getParam('name')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Name is missing'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('comment')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Comment is missing'));
        }
        if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid email address'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('hideit')) !== '') {
            throw new \Exception();
        }

        return $request->getParams();
    }
}
```

**/var/www/html/ajaffe/app/code/Amy/Contactform/Model/Mail.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Amy\Contactform\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

class Mail implements MailInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $contactsConfig;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param StoreManagerInterface|null $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->contactsConfig = $contactsConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Send email from contact form
     *
     * @param string $replyTo
     * @param array $variables
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($recipient, $replyTo, array $variables)
    {
        /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
        $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

        if ($recipient == 'General feedback'){
        $emails = ['aaa@gmail.com' , 'bbb@gmail.com'];  // add your email list
        }else if ($recipient == 'Warranty'){
        $emails = ['ccc@gmail.com' , 'ddd@gmail.com'];  // add your email list 
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($emails)
                //->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can get post params in post controller and set recipients according to you selection

Comment: I have tried it, but not able to achieve my target.

Comment: Hey is seems like your file isn't overridden properly. so make it working in vendor first then comes to override things to get it done @Amy

Comment: Okay I will check

Comment: Disable your module and do it in vendor @Amy

Comment: I have tried in vendor also, It is not working.

Comment: Is other email are going? from your server

Comment: Yep, it is going

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91028/discussion-between-prathap-gunasekaran-and-amy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Override post controller from the below path

> vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

change the sendEmail funtion to below code

```
private function sendEmail($post)
{
    $this->mail->send(
        $post['select_input_name'], 
        $post['email'],
        ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
    );
}
```

> NOTE : $post['select_input_name'] **select_input_name** should be your input name.

then change override Mail.php from the below path

> vendor/magento/module-contact/Model/Mail.php

replace the **send()** to below code

```
public function send($recipient, $replyTo, array $variables)
{
    /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
    $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;
    if ($recipient == 'option-1'){
        $emails = ['aaa@gmail.com' , 'ccc@gamil.com'];  // add your email list
    }else if ($recipient == 'option-2'){
        $emails = ['bbb@gmail.com' , 'eee@gmail.com'];  // add your email list 
    }

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try {
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($variables)
            ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
            ->addTo($emails)
            ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
    } finally {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Prathap. I will try your answer and will let you know.

Comment: Hi Prathap, I have tried this.. It is not working.. the email is not sending..

Comment: I have updated my question..

Answer (score 0):

For an email builder I recommend you to try free the Postcards — https://designmodo.com/postcards/

This tool is the perfect combined with tools you have mentioned.